# What is the applications of kmp algorithm?

Tags: search-problem, string-search

KMP algorithm works best when there is/are self matching(s) of pattern string that we want to search for. Usually it doesn't happen unless pattern is long enough. So where is the KMP application in real world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real world KMP algorithm is used in those applications where pattern matching is done in long strings, whose symbols are taken from an alphabet with little cardinality. A relevant example is the DNA alphabet, which consists on only 4 symbols (A,C,G,T). Imagine how KMP can work in a "DNA pattern matching problem": it is really suitable because many repetition of the same letter allows many jumps, and so less computation time wasted. If you are interested in this resarching area just google "DNA pattern matching algorithms", there's a lot to say.

Comment: Yes, thanks that was helpful. These applications of computer science in other fields of science makes it really useful, not just science for science.